# Why is present continuous used in "A key goal is learning to read"?

Tags: tenses, syntactic-analysis

> A key goal is *learning to read* a matrix.

Why is present continuous used here? As I understand *goal* is a final state. So *learning* is the process, to achieve something, not the goal itself. So this sentence should be like:

> A key goal is to be *learnt* how to read matrices.

So actual goal is to know how to read them, not learning it. Is this correct?

**EDIT**: I'm trying to understand, is the goal is the process of learning or the goal is the final state after you've learned, i.e. the goal is to know how to read, which is acquired by learning.

Comment: I just missed comma after Noah so it sounded like he fixed. But I was just addressing him, like: Noah, I fixed the sentence ... my apologies.

Comment: Oh, so the fix was yours and not Noah's? Then I'll delete my comment. But I still don't understand what Noah meant by "the sentence is ungrammatical", and I notice that his comment has been deleted. @Noah: Sorry, Noah. Well, I guess that shows that punctuation is sometimes good for something and that omitting some commas can change the meaning of a sentence. I always knew that there was a reason for commas and other punctuation.

Comment: @BillFranke, yes, it was my fix.

Comment: English Student: But you omitted the optional colon (:) after @Noah **AND** forgot to capitalize "fixed" **AND** omitted the optional subject **"I"**. Three tiny glitches that broke the semanticamel's back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you mention ‘present continuous’ in the question title, I think you may have read *is learning* as a present continuous construction. It is not. The subject of the sentence is *a key goal*, the verb is *is* and the complement, more precisely, the subject predicative, is *learning to read a matrix*.  *Learning* is derived from the verb *learn*, but here it functions as a noun, describing the process of acquiring knowledge.

Murphy covers uses of the *-ing* forms of the verb compared with *to* followed by the plain form of the verb in Units 55 to 57 of ‘English Grammar in Use’.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Now I understand the structure of the sentence. 
I only don't fully understand the meaning. The goal is **learning**, rather than the goal is **knowing how to read** (acquired by leaning). Right?

Comment: It’s hard to be sure without the full text, and without a knowledge of the subject under discussion. I assume that _read_ has a rather specialised sense in the context of matrices. In that case, the sentence would mean that a major objective is acquiring the ability to understand a matrix.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a present continuous because the subject of the sentence, **"goal"** is incapable of learning anything. It can be rewritten as:

> **"A key goal is to learn to 'read' a matrix."**

If it were "John is learning to 'read' a matrix", then the sentence would be present progressive.

*learning to "read" a matrix* is a gerund phrase. As Barrie England says, it functions as a noun phrase, the subject complement.